# waiting for setContentView() method

Tags: android, android-layout

I have problem with getting information about views after calling `setContentView()`. I'm changing layout of activity after click on button. Here is the example of my code.

```
public void onClickButton1(View v) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setScreen(); 
}
```

But durring execution `setScreen()` method, layout still is not rendered, so I cannot call `getWidth()` on some view intended in layout (respectively I can but I always get 0). How I can wait until `setContentView()` is finished? Please notice that using of this:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    setScreen();
}
```

is not sufficient for me. I need to change layout independently on activity cycle.

Comment: Can I ask why you are doing it this way instead of using a new `Activity` or `Fragments`? This typically isn't a good way to do it, IMHO

Comment: I'm quite new in android developing and It has seemed to me as a easiest way how to do it. May be I should change my approach. Thanks a lot

Comment: While i agree with codeMagic about using activities and fragments, for someone who is learning their way through coding for android i suggest do what ever works in the mean time.. Just be aware it may not be the best for memory/device support/stability. Once you start to get your mind around Java and the android/gradle development, then you you will find you'll remake/recode your application anyway within days of learning an efficient method/way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach a ViewTreeObserver to your layout:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.yourLayoutName);
    View yourLayout = findViewById(R.id.ID_OF_YOUR_LAYOUT);
    ViewTreeObserver vto = yourLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            //Do your work
            vto.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
```

Comment: @Mara Please accept the answer as the solution by clicking the check mark on the left in that case

Comment: While still learning my way around Java in some aspects, while using this with my fragments. The ViewTreeObserver vto object needs to be a final.. this is because if removeOnGlobalLayoutListener being called in the onGlobalLayout

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to use `setContentView()` to get the result you want. You either need to entirely remove all views and then inflate the new layout, use a `ViewFlipper` to switch between different views, or, which is IMHO the best approach, rework your app to use `Fragments`

Comment: There's no limit to how many times you can call `setContentView(...)`. It makes it a pain to manage multiple layouts in one activity but its possible.

Comment: no, but there's no easy way to make use of `setContentView()` to reach what OP wants. I will edit my answer as it may be misleading